# PayPal Adaptive Payment (Chained Payment) Integration in Android

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am integrating PayPal Adaptive payment in my apps and searching for solution of my problem.If any one had implemented chained payment in android  please provide me help.

Problem:-

When integrating chained payment in my app using PayPal_MPL.jar.Its working fine for me but there is a problem that there is no credit card payment option in paypal dialog.

Thanks

I am referring this [link](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_merchantsetupadministrationguide.pdf)

Comment: [link](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_merchantsetupadministrationguide.pdf) is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
first implement method
   private void initLibrary() {
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        if(pp == null) {
            pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, PAYPAL_APP_ID, PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
            pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.
            pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
//            pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
            pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
        }
    }    



**paypal button click event code**

     double secondary_payment = 0;
    double primary_payment = 0;

      PayPalAdvancedPayment advPayment = makeChainedPayment(secondary_payment,primary_payment,"primary_email","secondary_email");

      Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(advPayment, your_current_activity);
                    startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1); 

    =============================================
    private PayPalAdvancedPayment makeChainedPayment(double priceSecondary, double pricePrimary, String primary_email, String secondary_email) {
            PayPalAdvancedPayment payment = new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
            payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
    //        payment.setMerchantName("PushND");
            BigDecimal bigDecimalPrimary=new BigDecimal(pricePrimary);
            PayPalReceiverDetails receiverPrimary = new PayPalReceiverDetails();
            receiverPrimary.setRecipient(primary_email);
            //receiverPrimary.setRecipient("adaptive_receiver_1@pushnd.com");
            receiverPrimary.setSubtotal(bigDecimalPrimary);
            receiverPrimary.setIsPrimary(true);
            payment.getReceivers().add(receiverPrimary);

            PayPalReceiverDetails receiverSecondary= new PayPalReceiverDetails();
            receiverSecondary.setRecipient(secondary_email);
            BigDecimal bigDecimalSecond=new BigDecimal(priceSecondary);
            receiverSecondary.setSubtotal(bigDecimalSecond);
            payment.getReceivers().add(receiverSecondary);

            return payment;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below link and check for your answer...

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

```
 PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
             launchChainedPayment = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
             launchChainedPayment.setOnClickListener(this);




private void initLibrary() {
              PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
              if(pp == null) {
                     pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, Constant.PAYPAL_APP_ID, Constant.server);
                     pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.
                     pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER); 
                     pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
                     pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
              }
             }
         private PayPalAdvancedPayment makeChainedPayment(double priceDouble,double pricePrimary,String primary_email,JSONObject jsonObject) {
                PayPalAdvancedPayment payment = new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
                payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
                payment.setMerchantName("PushND");
                BigDecimal bigDecimalPrimary=new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(priceDouble));
                PayPalReceiverDetails receiverPrimary = new PayPalReceiverDetails();
                receiverPrimary.setRecipient(primary_email);
                //receiverPrimary.setRecipient("adaptive_receiver_1@pushnd.com");
                receiverPrimary.setSubtotal(bigDecimalPrimary);
                receiverPrimary.setIsPrimary(true);
                payment.getReceivers().add(receiverPrimary);
            try {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectSecondary = jsonObject;
                    Iterator<Object> keys = jsonObjectSecondary.keys();
                    while (keys.hasNext())
                    {
                        String Key=String.valueOf(keys.next());
                        PayPalReceiverDetails receiverSecondary= new PayPalReceiverDetails();
                        receiverSecondary.setRecipient(jsonObjectSecondary.getJSONObject(Key).get("email").toString());
                       //   receiverSecondary.setRecipient("adaptive_receiver_2@pushnd.com");
                        double priceSecondary=priceDouble*((Double.parseDouble(jsonObjectSecondary.getJSONObject(Key).get("profit_percent").toString()))/100);
                        BigDecimal bigDecimalSecondary=new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(priceSecondary));
                        receiverSecondary.setSubtotal(bigDecimalSecondary);
                        receiverSecondary.setIsPrimary(false);
                        payment.getReceivers().add(receiverSecondary);
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return payment;
     }
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.